# Count lines up from the bottom when 2nd column goes non-zero

Tags: awk

Here is a subset of a file for gnuplot with time in secs from 1/1/2000 and daily rainfall in mm:

```
        559008000   13.500000    
        559094400   2.4000001    
        559180800  0.60000002    
        559267200   13.800000    
        559353600   6.3000002    
        559440000  0.30000001    
        559526400   0.0000000    
        559612800   0.0000000    
        559699200   0.0000000    
        559785600   0.0000000
```

I want to find the number of days since it rained (it's 4).
First step is to reverse the file:

```
tac rainfile.txt
```

Now I'm looking for the first non-zero entry in column 2.

```
tac rainfile.txt | awk '$2 == "0.0000000" {++count} END {print count}'
```

gives me the total number of lines with zero, but how do I stop counting when I first hit a non-zero value?

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow, I almost got your question. Could you please add expected output too here once and let us know then?

Comment: numerous ways to write this, but you can use an old-school code-block, like `awk '{if ($2 == "0.0000000"){++count}else{exit}END{print count}'`. Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

I would just use `awk`, `tac` is not needed here:

```
awk '$2>0{d=0;next}{d++}END{print d}' rain.txt
```

`tac` needs to loop through the file anyway. Sure, it does not need to compare numbers, but unless `rainfile.txt` is really huge you shouldn't feel a difference. Otherwise see below...

---

About your initial solution with `tac`, just add a `next` and an `exit` statement:

```
tac rain.txt | awk '$2 == "0.0000000"{++count;next}{exit}END{print count}'
```

Note that `awk` will process the `END` block after `exit` has been called.

Comment: Yes!! That works.  But I'm not sure why.  I need to investigate "next" ...

Comment: `next` skips the remaining block of code ( `d++` ) and continues with the next line of input.

Comment: You can also write the first example like `awk '{d++}$2>0{d=0}END{print d}' rain.txt` but that would be slightly less efficient since you need to increase `d` in situations where it is not required.

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try following and let me know if this helps.

```
awk '($2==0){count++;next} {count=0} END{print count}'  Input_file
```

Output will be `4` for same. Explanation will be simple, check if any 2nd field is equal to zero, if yes then increase variable named count's value to 1 and use next to skip all further statements. If this condition doesn't satisfy in any line then it will not come in this block and it will nullify the value of count. Finally when all lines are read in END bock print the variable count which is 4.

Comment: @hek2mgl, thanks a TON sir for letting me know I didn't understand the meaning of rain :) that is why I asked OP. I edited my solution now. Kindly let me know if any changes needed, thank you again.

Comment: Why do you set `d=""`? You can use `d=0`

Answer (score -1):

You can `grep` the lines you want and get the last one via `tail`:

```
grep '^ *[0-9]\+  [0-9.]*[1-9][0-9.]*' input | tail -1
```

this gives:

```
559440000  0.30000001
```

to get the line number:

```
echo $(( $(tac in | grep -n '  [1-9][0-9.]* *$' -m 1 | cut -f1 -d:) - 1))
```

which gives:

```
 4
```

Comment: So how do I count the number of lines that follow this one?

Comment: Doable using grep but it won't be nice. However, you can actually use the timestamps to calculate the date difference using `date`.